# jquery multiple events issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Testing a very simple HTML with jQuery and cannot get it to work.

I have a `button id="button_calls"` that when clicked I want to hide a div with `id="tab_content_all_activity"` and show a div with `id="tab_content_calls"`.

I've declared a css class `is-active` and `is-inactive` which trigger `display: block` and `display:none` respectively.

```
$("#button_calls").click(
    function() {
        $("#tab_content_calls").removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
    },
    function() {
        $("#tab_content_all_activity").removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");
    });
```

However when I click on the button nothing happens. When I remove the second function and only keep the first function then the `id="tab_content_calls"` does indeed become active. In other words, I can't do both: show one div and hide the other. Solutions? Please help.

Comment: Passing two functions to `click` does not make sense to begin with. Go check the documentation, instead of guessing! https://api.jquery.com/click/ You can clearly see there, that the signature with two parameters takes an object of data to pass to the callback function, as first parameter - and a signature that takes two functions, is not actually mentioned there.

Comment: Go look into https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ - that allows you to switch a class on/off alternately, without you having to explicitly keep track of the current state yourself.

Comment: If you want to run more than one line of code, just include all the lines you want inside the (single) `function()` callback:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0kgy4m/

Comment: Also note that you don't need to toggle *both* classes, you can have a default then add/remove a class that overrides that default.  This makes your code substantially clearer and easier to read.  eg the default would be `inactive` (hidden), then when you make it `active` it's shown just by adding the `active` class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rethink your solution a little bit so that you have a single function that toggles with a conditional, checking for an attribute on your element.

Psuedocode For example:

```
Element.OnClick => function {
    if(Element.isActive)
        change style classes
        and set isActive = false
    else
        change style classes
        and set isActive = true
}
```

You don't need to manage an attribute though, you could compare for the classes you have already defined and then toggle them, however I recommend to abstract the result from the measurement to have a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle both statements inside the first function, there is no need for 2nd function. Check below possible solution:

Your code:

```
$("#button_calls").click(
    function() {
        $("#tab_content_calls").removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
    },
    function() {
        $("#tab_content_all_activity").removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");
    }
);
```

Possible solution for your issue:

```
$("#button_calls").click(
    function() {
        $("#tab_content_calls").removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
        $("#tab_content_all_activity").removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");
    }
);
```